# Passing "value" from slider to an element, as an parameter of an attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I'm trying to capture an `HTML`  `slider` `value`, which is suppose to set a parameter of an attribute (inside a `CSS` class).

So, i have a `slider` and a `div` element - to which i want to pass a value to:

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="11" value="6" class="slider" id="slider">

<div id="container">
     <div id="fg2">text</div>
</div>
```

In JS I've set those two elements as variables, and added `Event Listener` to the `slider`, with a function that captures `value` from the `slider`:

```
const slider = document.getElementById("slider")
const FGElement = document.getElementById("fg2");

slider.addEventListener("input", function(){
    changeSize();
});

function changeSize() {
    let i = slider.valueAsNumber;
    console.log(i);
}
```

Now, i want to add a class to `FGElement`, inside of which i would put `flex-grow: [i]`. Which is my idea to how dynamically capture `value` from `slider` to `FGElement`.

Is it the right way to do it, if so - how to set an parameter of an `CSS` `class` `attribute` in JS?

If not, what would be the correct way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't dynamically change values of `.css` file

You have to Use JS for to apply inline style

```
document.getElementById('myElement').style.flexGrow = i;
```